# Change application access user right in odoo 12

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

i want to change application access user right.
in Mark Demo, Administration is selection field and it has rights for **Access Rights**.
i want to change it to **Settings**.
in python file `self.env.user.has_group('base.group_system')` returns False.
it means in selection field it fielded with **Blank or Access right**.
how can i change it to **Settings**.

i found this group in base.

```
<record model="res.groups" id="group_system">
    <field name="name">Settings</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_erp_manager'))]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root')), (4, ref('base.user_admin'))]"/>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we change the value of `Administration` field and click on `save` button Odoo as usual calls `write` method, the first thing Odoo does, in this case, is calling [_remove_reified_groups](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py#L1177) method to remove `reified group fields` (`sel_groups_2_3` in your example) from values and compute the value of `groups_id` then add it to values to be written in the next step (when calling super).

`_remove_reified_groups` compute groups to add or remove from `groups_id`. if a `reified group field` is present in values and has a value it will be added to `groups_id`, each time a `reified group field` is present in values the method calls [get_selection_groups(key)](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py#L1197) to compute the groups to remove, the method returns the groups ids present in the field name. for the administration field `sel_groups_2_3` the method will return `[2, 3]`.

To reproduce the same result when updating `Administration` group we need to remove the groups used in field name then add the selected group to `groups_id` (`values['groups_id'] = [(3, 2), (3, 3), (4, 3)]`)

The XML code used to set `Mark demo` administration group to `Settings` group should be:

```
<record id="base.user_demo" model="res.users">
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(3,ref('base.group_erp_manager')),(3,ref('base.group_system')),(4,ref('base.group_system'))]"/>
</record>
```